# How to get aggregated logs of application submitted on yarn via web ui of Ambari log search service

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm not able to find the logs of application I have submitted on the the yarn on ambari cluster via log search service.

Answer (score 0):

You can access logs from CLI using `yarn logs -applicationId <application ID>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the log file associated with the log message that you are searching for. Then see if this particular component is configured in log search. Maybe it's not configured. That is one reason why log search is not picking up the log message
If it is configured there could be additional reasons why log search is not picking the log message

1) Check the filter set for the component. Maybe the filter is set to pick up only ERROR and WARN and the log message you are trying to see could be INFO

2)While configuring log search components you can set a filter. Make sure the log message matches the filter